# Avoiding Duplicate Code when one Switch cases intersects other cases

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement

I need to write a block of code where one set of statements executes if variable's value is option A, another set of statements executes if the value is option B, and both sets of statements execute if the value is both A and B (do nothing if it's neither A nor B).

I know this is relatively straightforward using `if/else`. However, I'd like to do it with a switch statement for code safety (compiler checks on `switch` being exhaustive) and readability. I'm looking at something like this, but it mixes `switch` with `if/else` to manage control flow. It's ugly, and I'm wondering if anybody knows a better way.

```
enum myEnum{
   case optionA
   case optionB
   case both
   case neither
}

switch value {
   case .optionA, .both:
   //Executed when value is myEnum.optionA or myEnum.both
   if( value == myEnum.both){
      fallthrough
   }

   case .optionB:
   //Executed when value is myEnum.optionB or myEnum.both

   default:
   //covers everything else
}
```

Some notes on things that don't work:

You can't have

```
case .optionA, .both:
   //code
case .optionB, .both:
   //more code
```

because when `value` is `.both`, flow of execution will exit the switch statement after `//code` statements execute, without executing the `//more code` statements.

This also doesn't work:

```
case .optionA, .both:
   //code
   fallthrough
case .optionB:
   //more code
```

since that will cause the `.optionB` statements to execute when `value` is `.optionA`.

And of course the whole point of asking this question is to avoid doing something like:

```
case .optionA:
   //code
case .optionB:
   //more code
case .optionB:
   //code
   //more code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think what you're asking is possible (see [docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html)). The point of an enum is to define unique cases. You are trying to define a case that is a combination of two other cases *in the same enum*.

In reality what you have are two distinct options that can be selected or not. You would probably be better off modeling it this way, if you can:

```
enum OptionSelection {
    case selected
    case notSelected
}

var optionA: OptionSelection?
var optionB: OptionSelection?
```

But obviously this doesn't provide the solution you were hoping for. I just don't think it's possible.